# type INode* is pointer to interface, not interface

Tags: go

So trying out go for the first time today and keep running into an error to do with interfaces, I guess I don't understand them correctly. Ive tried looking around for an answer but the terminology that I'm used to is a little different from other languages so I can't piece it together. As practice I decided to implement a very simple linked list but the error I recieve is:

`type INode* is pointer to interface, not interface` when calling `.setNext(node *Inode)`

What is the reason behind this? what piece of information am I missing with interfaces?

Heres the incomplete implementation:

```
package main

type object interface{}

type INode interface {
    GetData() object
    GetNext() *INode
    setNext(node *INode)
}

type ILinkedList interface {
    Link(node *INode)
    Unlink(node *INode)
    CurrentLength() int
    RemoveAt(idx int)
}

type Node struct {
    data object
    next *INode
}

func (n *Node) GetData() object {
    return n.data
}

func (n *Node) GetNext() *INode {
    return n.next
}

func (n *Node) setNext(node *INode) {
    n.next = node
}

type LinkedList struct {
    cur    *INode
    last   *INode
    length int
}

func (l *LinkedList) Link(node *INode) {
    if l == nil {
        return
    }
    if l.cur == nil {
        l.cur = node
        l.last = node
    } else {
        l.last.setNext(node)
        l.last = node
    }
    l.length = l.length + 1
}
```

Comment: Go is not Java and you cannot program Java in Go. Take the Tour of Go. Never use a pointer to interface (rule of thumb). You mixed up your types.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but can really only go off what I already know until I learn the "go" way. Is there a way to coerce it to its correct type? I understand you said don't use pointers to interfaces, I understand that an interface can have an underlying pointer type and concrete type. I just don't get why this doesn't work. It seems weird that *INode !== *INode.

Comment: `*INode` doesn't have a method `setType`. `INode` does. You get the error because pointers to interfaces have no methods at all, so calling a method on a pointer to interface is always wrong.

Comment: Your `last` field in `LinkedList` is of type `*INode`. Now the type `*INode` does _not_ have a `setNext` method, only type `Inode` "has" a `setNext`. Really: Never ever use pointer to interface as this does not work! It is not about *INode !== *INode it is about the methods set of your type `INode` (which is explicit as it is an interface type, you listed them all) and the method set of `*INode` and how you may call such a method. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors point 3.)

Comment: So in other words I can do (*l.last).setNext() ? Ahh, I thought it was automatically dereferenced but I guess that is only for structs.

Comment: So is there actually any use of interface pointers then? Why not just make them illegal?

Comment: The little magic autodereferencing is for structs mainly. And yes, there are valid (albeit advanced) use cases for pointers to interface. But these are rare. E.g. if you want to change the interface value from within a function. "Never use a pointer to an interface" is a very good rule. You should break it only if you actually understand why the rule exists and then you will know how and why to do it.

Answer (score 3):

This is because in Go, an interface is just a specification of behavior.  This behavior can be implemented with either a pointer receiver or a value receiver.  The interface doesn't care which one is ultimately used, just as long as it fulfills the interface contract.

See this example:
https://play.golang.org/p/0AaBhB1MHBc

```
type I interface {
    M()
}

type T struct {
    S string
}
func (t T) M(){
    fmt.Println("T.M fired");
}

type S struct {
    S string
}
func (s *S) M(){
    fmt.Println("*S.M fired");
}

func RunM(i I){
    i.M()
}
func main() {
    test1 := T{}
    test2 := &S{}
    RunM(test1)
    RunM(test2)
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Both pointers to the S type and T types implement the interface I, and can be passed in to any func requiring an I.  The interface doesn't care if it's a pointer or not.

You can read up about pointer receivers here: https://tour.golang.org/methods/4

Comment: Thanks for the references, I understand this bit and now understand what I was doing wrong previously!

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would post a reference for those visiting in the future that have the same issue regarding pointers to interfaces:

**When should I use a pointer to an interface?**

> Almost never. Pointers to interface values arise only in rare, tricky
>   situations involving disguising an interface value's type for delayed
>   evaluation.
>
> It is however a common mistake to pass a pointer to an interface value
>   to a function expecting an interface. The compiler will complain about
>   this error but the situation can still be confusing, because sometimes
>   a pointer is necessary to satisfy an interface. The insight is that
>   although a pointer to a concrete type can satisfy an interface, with
>   one exception a pointer to an interface can never satisfy an
>   interface.
>
> Consider the variable declaration,
>
> var w io.Writer The printing function fmt.Fprintf takes as its first
>   argument a value that satisfies io.Writer—something that implements
>   the canonical Write method. Thus we can write
>
> fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello, world\n") If however we pass the address of w,
>   the program will not compile.
>
> fmt.Fprintf(&w, "hello, world\n") // Compile-time error. The one
>   exception is that any value, even a pointer to an interface, can be
>   assigned to a variable of empty interface type (interface{}). Even so,
>   it's almost certainly a mistake if the value is a pointer to an
>   interface; the result can be confusing.